# Importing angular modules from external project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show two modules / components in my angular project, that are actually in another project.

Is there a way I can import them and show both components on one page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to know how it is done in Angular 2.0?

Comment: Oh ups. No I am talking about AngularJS 1.x